# Jquery, read data attribute from all divs that match proper pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have html code that looks like this:

```
<select id="invoice_line_items_attributes_0_product_id" class="select required form-control" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][0][product_id]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="34" data-price="123.0">asdsad</option>
<option value="35" data-price="123213.0">asd</option>
</select>

<select id="invoice_line_items_attributes_1_product_id" class="select required form-control" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][0][product_id]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="31" data-price="1223.0">asdsad</option>
<option value="32" data-price="12333213.0">asd</option>
</select>
```

And now I want to iterate through all this selects and when one of this change this value alert this date-price attribute. I trying to do this with the following code:

```
  $('[id*="product"]').each ->
    $(this).change ->
      alert  $(this).attr("data-price")
```

But It gaves me undefined instead of this data-price value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

1) You do not need to iterate over select element individually and then bind the even. Selector will do that on its own for matched elements.

2) You need to find selected option and then get data price value.

3) use `.data()` instead of using `.attr()` to get data attribute values.

Use:

```
$('[id*="product"]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/5r1wzzo2/)**

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `select` doesn't have `data-attr`, I think you want the selected options `data-attr`.

And to get `data-attributes` jquery provides `.data` function.

do like bellow.

```
$('[id*="product"]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/73/)